# Shell Script to Check if Website is Down Programatically

Tags: shell, unix, curl

I'm trying to develop a simply shell script to determine if a list of my websites are down or not. Most of the solutions I've seen involve making a `curl` request and checking the status code that is returned.

Today I ran into 2 similar situations where that would have failed. First, my site's root web folder had somehow been emptied and when I visited the home page, I got a directory listing page (i.e. Index of "/"...). The status code returned was 200, but the site was definitely down. Second, my host (for some reason) disabled my site. I get a "Website Disabled" message and a 200 response code.

So, clearly checking the response code alone isn't enough, but I can't predict what message may be displayed in the event a site goes down. Any ideas to get me started on a more robust solution?

**Edit:**
Some more details as requested by @Danduk82:

- A: I'm not 100% sure what you mean by "root" access. I have SFTP and SSH access, but I don't have super user privileges on the servers where they are hosted. They are not my servers, and they are on a shared host (not a dedicated or virtual root environment).
- B: I'm talking about 10-12 websites currently. But, I'm trying to build a somewhat scalable system.
- C: The sites are all hosted on *nix based platforms. Right now, I believe they are on a FreeBSD platform, but they have been on some flavor of Linux in the past, and it might change again in the future (out of my hands).

**Edit 2:**
Based on the answers provided here, I made a little shell script to accomplish this task. Here's a link to the [gist on github](https://gist.github.com/dominic-p/8729136) in case someone else will find it useful. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Could you edit your questions and pelase tell: a) do have root access to the websites? (You say "your websites"). b) approximately how many they are? c) their operating system (if you are root)

Comment: add something to be output on your site if it's up, like a meta tag or comment or something.  Then use `cURL` and scrape for it. If you get a 200 response and it's not there, then you will know it's an index page or 'website disabled' type response

Comment: @CrayonViolent, that's not a bad idea. It would be kind of a pain to remember to keep that special comment or meta tag there whenever the site is redesigned though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy trick I have used for this kind of checks is to place a text.txt file in the root whose only content is `works`. This is easily searchable with curl. Something like:

curl /text.txt | grep -c works

You could do it from a configuration file:

```
cat file| while read line 
do
   line (curl command for every line)
done
```

(aprox syntax, do not trust directly as I cannot check now)